# Hibernate Tools - NullPointerException - TablePropertiesBlock

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate

I want to develop a small prototype of a application. I have create a database on MySQL 5.6. They have only 2 tables - one reference from mastertable to childtable (It´s like a easy prototype). All tables have a Id-column.

I using the eclipse 4.4.1 (x86 on Windows 7 x64 - german), Hibernate 4.3.8, Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 (Final).

I can create all the steps in the turtorials I found (create a hibernate.cfg.xml, console config and hibernate.reveng.xml)

Now I want to customize my reveng.xml. I will configure the settings of the columns. But I cant put them in the reveng.xml with the "Tables & Column"-Dialog. I use the "Add"-Button and the tables are shown and can selected. But if i press the "ok"-button the selection will not send to the xml.

What I doing wrong? Have I forget something?

Here the Errorlog-Details of Eclipse:

```
Unhandled event loop exception
```

The Exception Stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.eclipse.mapper.editors.reveng.TablePropertiesBlock.doAdd(TablePropertiesBlock.java:209)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.mapper.editors.reveng.TablePropertiesBlock$1.widgetSelected(TablePropertiesBlock.java:127)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

And the Session data

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_67
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```